# Extracting RMSE from a lmList object

Tags: r, plyr, lme4

I have the following code to extract the Coefficients from a lmList object.

```
library(lme4)
library(plyr)
lm.model <- lmList(Y ~ X | eventID, df)
param <- ldply(lm.model, coef)
```

This code is working OK. HOwever, is this an efficient way to extract the coefficients?

My main question is, how can I extract RMSE from the same lm.model object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case ldply is not necessary to get coefficients (you can simply use coef(lm.model)).
To get residual standard error:

```
ldply(slot(lm.model,".Data"),function(x) summary(x)$sigma)
```

Comment: It works, I was close to get it correct... I didn't know that it is called sigma in R. Thanks.